# 1 HTML5 code to rule them all

Tags: html

We're new to mobile. We have our HTML5 page (w/ PHP) up and running live. We now want to go mobile. Whether it's a native app or mobile web doesn't make a difference in our situation. We just want to have 1 set of code to maintain (with only minor tweaks here or there for different platforms). We've played around somewhat with Titanium & Phonegap but it seems like we have to make a LOT of modifications to our HTML5 code.

When people talk about a "mobile web app" (ie http://techcrunch.com/2011/11/18/financial-times-mobile/) what do they mean? Is it simply loading our HTML5 website from an iphone? If not, what development frameworks should we use? thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see much difference between a mobile web app and a web app. Browsers on smartphones are sometimes even better then browsers people use at home...

Things you should really keep in mind are screen sizes and no mouseover effects.

Common used technologies for a mobile web app are:

HTML 5, CSS , JS , jQuery, [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) (which was released 1.0 a few days ago!)

Server technologies are pretty much the same.

In order to generate the impression of a native app you could then use Phonegap.

Comment: "I don't see much difference between a mobile web app and a web app."...but what is a web app? It might be a stupid question, but if it's just a website, why does that techcrunch article call it a "mobile web app" rather than a "mobile webpage"? Are they the same?

Comment: In fact a mobile webpage is a mobile webapp...
But in the last years a lot technologies like html5 and javascript are getting more powerful, so that you can creat "real" apps, with those technologies. Thats why some websites are called web-apps. For example Google Docs is a great example for a web app

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the [Sencha](http://www.sencha.com/) framework for mobile apps. It makes your HTML5 app look like, and feel like a native app for any phone OS.

Comment: "It makes your HTML5 app look like..."....but why do you & they call it a webapp when it's just a website? In that case, why do I need Sencha? Sorry to be a pain but just having a hard time understanding

Answer (score 0):

You can surely implement a mobile web application by implementing it as a web application.  Obviously you have to give special consideration to the targeted mobile devices, and do lots of prototyping & testing.  Browsers are really getting better on the mobile devices - so that's something good.

If you can create the experience you want in a web application, then great!  As of now many developers find it worthwhile to write applications that directly target mobile devices, while also providing a web application.  Once you have multiple kinds of clients, it's a good idea to implement the functionality in your application in a web API, which is accessible to the various clients (web app (browser), iOS app, Android app, etc.).

Comment: I guess my question is more around "what is a mobile web app?" (I know what a mobile native app is)